Line plot with ggplot several lines and secondary axis
I am trying to get a line plot with ggplot with two lines for the y-axis on the left and one line for the secondary axis on the right.
I know how it works to get the seconary axis and in case of one line for the left axis everything works out well.
I think the problem is to display two lines on the left axis.
Here is an example of my data:
    years <- rep(c("2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022"), 3)
    legend <- c(rep("price1", 11), rep("price2", 11), rep("price3", 11))
    numbers <- c(8,3,14,10,16,19,26,23,9,3,16,2.0,0.6,3.0,2.1,3.3,4.1,6.1,6.0,3.4,1.4,5.6,
                           3943200,4694600,4644400,4876700,4792600,4610700,4239000,3832300,
                           2647500,2179400,2853700)
dataset <- data.frame(years, legend, numbers)

The numbers for price1 and price2 should be showed on the left axis and the numbers for price3 on the right axis.

One way is to split the data on the two groups of prices.
data1 <- filter(dataset, legend!="price3")
data2 <- filter(dataset, legend=="price3")

ggplot(data1, aes(x=years, y=numbers, col=legend, group=legend)) +
  geom_line(linewidth=1) +
  geom_line(data=data2, aes(y=numbers/100000), linewidth=1) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*100000, labels=scales::comma))


The scaling factor is about 1:200,000 but I chose 100,000 to separate the two groups a little.
